# MVC 5 asp.net, viewbag from controller to view is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the controller

```
public ActionResult Test() {

@ViewBag.TheMessageIs = "this is the message";
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = theId});

}
```

on the **view** of Action Named **Details** I will check if it has the ViewBag to show and show it:

```
@{
  if(ViewBag.TheMessageIs != null){
         @ViewBag.TheMessageIs
  }
}
```

but here the redirection is working fine to the page, it's not show the message I have stored in ViewBag.TheMessageIs

thanks

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing data from a controller to a view. Not from a controller method to another controller method (its lost as soon as you redirect). Use `TempData`, or pass the message as a route value to the other method (which will have a `string message` parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Test() {
 TempData["shortMessage"] = "MyMessage";
 return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = theId});
}

public ActionResult Details {
 //now I can populate my ViewBag (if I want to) with the TempData["shortMessage"] content
  ViewBag.TheMessageIs = TempData["shortMessage"].ToString();
  return View();
}
```

You have to do it like this since the viewbag looses its value when you redirect to another active / view

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you're doing is invoking the method `Details` from your `Index` method and since you're already overloading your Details action with an `id`, pass it the message as well:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //ViewBag.TheMessageIs = "this is the message";
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = 1, TheMessageIs = "this is the message" });
}

public ActionResult Details(int id, string TheMessageIs)
{
    ViewBag.TheMessageIs = TheMessageIs;
    return View();
}
```

Then in the Details view you can access the property like this:

```
@ViewBag.TheMessageIs
```