# How to pass alert or notification message from controller to View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, alert

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I am trying to send success and failure as some well defined box to my view from controller. My question may be duplicate, but, none of the answers worked for me.

The main code I tried:

```
public ActionResult Pay_EditSave()
{
     if(condition = true)
     {
          TempData["alertMessage"] = "Duplicate Record-Record already Exists!!!";
          return View();
     }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="box-body">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Pay_EditSave", "Master", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     if (TempData["alertMessage"] != null)
     {
         <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
             @TempData["alertMessage"].ToString()
         </div>
     }
}
</div>
```

Other than this, I tried many other viewbag / tempdata / return new JavascriptResult / return content answers too. None of it work for me. In console debugger, the code shows a "500 Internal error".

**Important note**: the code I have shown here is used in the Login page too. On that page, it is working properly. I don't know why this is not working for me in other pages. What am I doing wrong?

Kindly help.

Comment: Shouldn't  "if(condition =true)" be  "if(condition ==true)" ?

Comment: thats not an issue sir, may b here I got a typo,actually, I gave some coding conditions, and while debug,it satisfies the condition and enter the loop too.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that - usually it is the simpliest issues that catch us.

Comment: Welcome sir, Its actually I assign just to understand ,if condition true, then alert message need to trigger. My same code working in Login Page,but not in other pages. any Idea sir?

Comment: Recreated your environment, where have action result in controller, and set condition to true. It defininitely shows tempdata alert message in view. I would check condition again.

Comment: When I debug, no error prompt, but I inspect element debug page, I found out this erro `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Can you check if view is under correct controller ? e.g. Pay_EditSave.cshtml is int the same controller folder ? Had issue once where the view was under different controller and nothing ever happened.

Comment: active log and get complete error message

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis sorry for late rly, Pay_editsave in in same controller folder only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewBag or ViewData instead of TempData. Another approach is; you can use Session also.
If this doesnot solve your problem, please check below links, I hope you will find your solution.

[Any reason why my ViewBag is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447310/any-reason-why-my-viewbag-is-not-working)

[MVC 5 asp.net, viewbag from controller to view is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033943/mvc-5-asp-net-viewbag-from-controller-to-view-is-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag.obj1, ViewBag.obj2, ..., etc.

Comment: I tried viewbag too, but it not working for me